# Angular 6 dropdown list with free input

Tags: angular

In an Angular 6 project I'm using the [ngx-select-ex](https://github.com/optimistex/ngx-select-ex) component to input some values from a list. It works very good both for multiple and single selection.

Now I need to enhance it allowing the user to either select a value from the list or input a new value, which then will be the actual value. This would allow the user to select a value from the list of predefined ones or create a new one.

As far as you know, is there any ready component for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the [PrimeNg Autocomplete](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) component. It is both a free text input box and a select list from which you can select an item. The linked model will contain the value you selected or typed.